# running client-server app in c# xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio

I started using Xamarin Studio for c# development and I wrote two 'Projects' in one 'Solution' - Server and Client. When I run Server, everything goes well, but the problem is, that I don't know how to run client at the same time.
Please help how to run both at the same time. I've googled but found nothing.

Comment: In VS, you'd open another instance of VS and start the client project in that one - don't know if it's that easy in Xamarin Studio, too.

Comment: @germi: only in unusual circumstances.  Visual Studio has the option of launching (and debugging) multiple startup projects in a single instance of VS.  If both projects are in the same solution then multiple startup projects is the way to go.

Comment: I would recommend you to separate the client - server  projects into two different solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Solution options (right click the Solution in the Solution window and select Options) you can configure multiple startup projects in the Run - Startup Project section.

Testing this with Xamarin Studio 5.8 running two console apps, using Run - Start without Debugging, seems to work but debugging two console apps fails. Also you do not seem to be able to debug an ASP.NET app with a separate client app, but you can run both together without the debugger.

If you need to debug both then running two instances of Xamarin Studio will allow you to do that.

Comment: Just stressing that you should "run without debugging", or one of the applications will not start.